# plotting gaussian operator in 3D in matlab for (lambda 1 = lambda 2 >> lambda 3)

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, gaussian

My goal is to plot the gaussian operator in 3D in matlab.
Now I have my equation and I think the operator should be an oblate spheroid (for the case where we have large lambda1 and lambda2 compared to a small lambda 3) . Below is my attempt to do that. I tried to do it in two different ways: First using a mesh or alternatively by building the matrix itself. The command isosurface for plotting is something I picked up online that works for 3D plots.
Your comment and advice on this are much appreciated

```
    %% plot the gaussian 
clc
clear all
close all


 % define the variances (sigma1 , sigma2 and sigma3) which are essentially the three lambdas with lambda 1 and two close to each other and a small lambda 3. 

lambda1 = 3;
lambda2 = 2.5;
lambda3 = 0.5;

anorm=1/( (2.0*pi)^1.5 * sqrt( lambda1*lambda2*lambda3 ) );

%% building the matrix 

% I used this grid (from -5 : 4) to center the gaussian in the middle 
for x1=-5:4
    for x2=-5:4
        for x3=-5:4
g(x1+6,x2+6,x3+6) = anorm * exp(-0.5*((x1^2/lambda1)+(x2^2/lambda2)+(x3^2/lambda3))); 
        end 
    end 
end

%% second attempt

[i, j, k] = meshgrid(-5:4 , -5:4 ,-5:4); 

Gauss = anorm * exp(-0.5*((i.^2/lambda1)+(j.^2/lambda2)+(k.^2/lambda3)));

%% plotting
figure (1) 
isosurface(g)
grid on
xlabel('X', 'FontSize', 14)
ylabel('Y', 'FontSize', 14)
zlabel('Z', 'FontSize', 14)

figure (2) 
isosurface(Gauss)
grid on
xlabel('X', 'FontSize', 14)
ylabel('Y', 'FontSize', 14)
zlabel('Z', 'FontSize', 14)
```

Comment: So what is your question? The plots definitely look somehow spheroidal.. Is it `axis equal vis3d` you are looking for?

Comment: Bare in mind that you are visualizing 4 dimensional data, as you are trying to plot a function `R^3 -> R`, so it is quite likely that an isosurface approach won't be that satisfactory. Maybe just do some colored 2D cuts through the volume to visualize multiple `R^2->R` [data slices](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html). You could also animate the plot to show different thresholds of the functions range.

Comment: Yes ! you hit the nail right on the head there. I was trying to break my big matrix using reshape then plot is using another command but I am not there yet. I am seeking an opinion on how to make the link between the 3D data and the 3D plot in matlab. So my question is down to (am I constructing the 3D matrix in the correct way to plot it and which command will best serve me to plot it). Good shout on the vis3d, I appreciate that

Comment: I am sorry to tell you that this question is possibly too broad for stackoverflow: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam*. You could have a look at the MATLAB [docs](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/volume-visualization.html) instead, try to implement something, and come back with specific questions. As you said: There can only be opinions, but no answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you *did* produce a 3D iso-surface with the second plot.

It looks like you've also found that MATLAB has limited options for 3D plotting. When I have 3D data, I often prefer to look at a variety of slices, which is implemented in the script below.

Hope this helps!

```
%XY contours of 3d gaussian
figure
hold on

size_mat=100;   %number of grid elements
max_x=3;        %maxmimum spread in x and y
gg=zeros(size_mat, size_mat);   %gaussion function
fixed_z=5;      %fix z while taking this contour
delta_x=max_x/size_mat*2;   %spacing between grid points

%loop over grid
for i=1:size_mat
    for j=1:size_mat
        cur_x=-max_x+i*delta_x;
        cur_y=-max_x+j*delta_x;
        %computed value of 3d gaussian
        gg(i,j) = anorm * exp(-0.5*((cur_x.^2/lambda1)+(cur_y.^2/lambda2)*(fixed_z^2/lambda3)));
    end
end
%make contour plot
h=contour(gg)
%clabel(h)
title('Contour of 3d Gaussian with z=5')
```